# Display Mysql Results Alphabetically from two queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MYSQL queries as follows:

```
$anchors = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current' AND site_type = 'slave' LIMIT $links_nr");
```

// the second query has an offset = $links_nr

```
$anchors2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `anchors` WHERE `site_url` = '$site_current' AND `site_type` = 'slave' LIMIT $links_nr,99999");
```

**I want to display the results ordered alphabetically, how do you advise me to do it?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY site_url ASC` in your SQL query to sort the result set

```
$anchors2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current' AND site_type = 'slave' LIMIT $links_nr,99999 ORDER BY site_url ASC");
```

Comment: How do I use this but excluding an entry. E.g. I am returning countries but want to list "Others" in the default position bottom.  When I use ORDER BY with ASC it's affecting all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered saving and cocatenating the results as a multi-dimensional array, then using uasort() to re-arrange the array in alphabetical order? I've used this method quite a bit in the past with merged data-sets and it has worked great. Here's the uasort() function and a link if you're interested in further research:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

(the difference between this and usort is that usort does not maintain indexes - which could be damaging to your project:

```
<?php
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
}
return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);
print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
[a] => 4
[b] => 8
[c] => -1
[d] => -9
[e] => 2
[f] => 5
[g] => 3
[h] => -4
)
Array
(
[d] => -9
[h] => -4
[c] => -1
[e] => 2
[g] => 3
[a] => 4
[f] => 5
[b] => 8
)
```